# How to create a SQL Server database programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I want to create a program, that will use SQL Server 2008 database. During the first start, I would like to open a window, which let the user create a database. It will be simply, textboxes with name and ip of the database computer to set and button "Go".

Program will be in WPF .NET4. And database will be in local network.

Could you suggest me a good solution? Is it a good programming practice, to do that? Or maybe I should just attached a sql script?

I do some research, I found that article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CreateSQLDV.aspx

But, first issue, in SQL Server 2008, there is no `Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll`. So, when I do similar "data create" window, but for SQL Server 2008 (using maybe different dlls) - It will not work for SQL Server 2005. And maybe will not work with other versions of SQL Server 2008 to? I don't know.. Example from codeproject looks good, but I'm not sure.

I would like to do a flexible program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid SMO.

It depends a LOT on your audience and the control you have over the expected environment, but attaching pre-made databases, while a convenient option, can sometimes have issues - to start with it's a binary under source control, so you don't get diffs for free in your source control system.  In addition, you're attaching a database with certain options and things which might not be appropriate for the specific target environment - SQL Server 2005, SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2?  Other than all that, it's a valid approach similar to the way one might deploy Access applications in the past.

In a less controlled environment, I would go with either generating a SQL script containing all the DDL (and DML for lookup tables) or providing a script, offering to run it automatically and also giving them the option of running it themselves with their own tools (if they have a DBA).

Now your script (or at least the template for the script or the code that generates the script) is under source control and can satisfy a DBA who wants to inspect it.

Comment: Well, my database is quite simple: It has tables (one with Image type), stored procedures, triggers and couple of views. That's all. So I think it is appropriate for 2005 SQL srever and latter.

Comment: @Marshall: as a side-note: if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you should **not** use the `IMAGE` type anymore - use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead....

Comment: @Marshall You cannot attach a SQL Server database file to an older version of SQL Server.  So if you have people on different versions of SQL Server, the empty database file you attach will need to be from the earliest version you need to support.  Same thing with doing restores for a backup file you provide.  This is an advantage of scripting, as I said, your scripts will run in the user's environment (and they can modify them if their environment is unique).  The question remains as to what the target users and their environments look like and what they expect.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks, I remember that i change it to IMAGE, because I've got some problems with files.. I thought there is no big difference between them. I will try to come back to varbinary soon.

Comment: @Cade Roux Well, you convinced me to use scripts, however, Do You suggest client of my program should run scripts in sql-server managment by himself?

Comment: @Marshall Only if they have DBA or environmental requirements.  Say you have an app which requires they login as sa or similar because it needs to create a database - they may have a requirement that the code be reviewed or audited.  Or that they create the database and the users AND ONLY THEN can your app set up objects like tables and procedures in the database since your setup program will only run as the user they set up for you.  Alternatively, if your app uses SQL Server Express or similar as a silent internal database, maybe you just use the attach feature.  It's hard to say right now.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend **not** to actually programmatically **create** the database. As you mentioned - with different versions of SMO, this becomes a bit of a nightmare.

My approach would be this:

- with your installation, ship a "default" empty database that has your base structure (all your tables and everything) and possibly also some basic lookup data in certain tables
- when the user indicates he doesn't have an existing database for your application, copy the MDF/LDF/and possibly NDF files to the SQL Server data location
- attach those database files programmatically to the SQL Server instance

That seems a nice cleaner and more flexible approach.

Comment: Well, I don't know (now) how to attach mdf and ldf files to SQL Server programmatically.By programmatically you mean from C# program? But if it's possible, I like that idea. But to attach these files user should pass login and password to the program (or authentication mode), right?

Comment: @Marshall: yes - sure - programmatically by issuing a normal T-SQL statement - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165673.aspx for more details!

Comment: So, I have to connect to the master database. Do you think attach mdf file is better than run "creating scripts"? What are pros and cons of these solutions?

Comment: @Marshall: ATTACH is usually much faster and only requires two files (MDF/LDF). Creating the whole database from a script is a bit cumbersome - scripts work great for updating your database with changes when it's in place already.

Comment: Yes, you right. But using scripts user can define size, recovery mode or name.. but then it will be slower. I think use both solution. User will have a choice, create database faster or create custom. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The database creation may not need to be a part of your code per se. Especially, if you only need to create the database once. I suggest an approach on which you create an installer either by using Windows Installer or Inno Setup (I prefer Inno Setup). With an installer you can prompt the user for their SQL server name and the login credentials for their administrative user. Then you can use those to run a SQL script containing your CREATE DATABASE and CREATE TABLE statements, etcetera. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know if I undestand corectly. You suggest to ask user for Server name, authentication and (in case of sql server auth.) login and passowrd. 

Then create a connection string to the "master" database. use master to create my database, tables etc.. Right?

Comment: Let me clarify. What I am suggesting is that you do away with performing the initial database housekeeping programatically in your C# code. A long time ago I created an installer using Windows installer that would invoke the SQL server command line utility with all the arguments it needs: server name, sa password, database name and path to your SQL script file containing the database/table creation statements.